# VBA Excel change column inside of formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula within a loop.

```
For x = 0 To dataLastColumn - 1
    wsModel.Cells(startCell + 3, 2 + x).Formula = "=(($B$34*B33)/B30)*B31"
Next x
```

For each x I'd like to change the column for the next one.
For example: if x = 1 than my desired formula would be -

```
wsModel.Cells(startCell + 3, 2 + 1).Formula = "=(($B$34*C33)/C30)*C31"
```

if x = 2

```
wsModel.Cells(startCell + 3, 2 + 2).Formula = "=(($B$34*D33)/D30)*D31"
```

Is there a way to change columns like that?

Comment: Without looping: `wsModel.Cells(startCell + 3, 2 + x).Resize(, dataLastColumn-1).Formula = "=(($B$34*B33)/B30)*B31"`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks, that's much easier!

Answer (score 0):

I Try This One Its Working

```
sModel.Cells(startCell + 3, 2 + x).Resize(, dataLastColumn-1).Formula = "=(($B$34*B33)/B30)*B31"
```